# Jasmin sms gateway- dlr ack with status code 200 ok is not working

Tags: python, php

```
# Python example to make an http api request
# http://jasminsms.com
import urllib.request, urllib.error, urllib.parse
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error

baseParams = {'username':'kk', 'password':'kk', 'to':'+251982767724', 'content':'Hello','dlr':'yes','dlr-level':'2','dlr-url':'http://localhost/php/ack.php','dlr-method':'POST'}

# Send an SMS-MT with minimal parameters
urllib.request.urlopen("http://127.0.0.1:1401/send?%s" % urllib.parse.urlencode(baseParams)).read()

# Send an SMS-MT with defined originating address
baseParams['from'] = 'Jasmin GW'
response=urllib.request.urlopen("http://127.0.0.1:1401/send?%s" % urllib.parse.urlencode(baseParams)).read()
print(response)
```

this is to be called by the dlr-thrower, it needs to be replied with a header 200 ok and ACG/jasmin body, but dlr-thrower cant seem to find my ack.py(the code below), i have tried the ones with in the comments too but still doesnot work

//this is what is required of me

When requested through dlr-* fields when Sending SMS-MT, a delivery receipt (DLR) will be sent back to the application url (set in dlr-url) through HTTP GET/POST depending on dlr-method.

The receiving end point must reply back using a “200 OK” status header and a body containing an acknowledgement of receiving the DLR, if one or both of these conditions are not met, the DLRThrower service will consider reshipment of the same message if config/dlr-thrower/max_retries is not reached (see jasmin.cfg / dlr-thrower).

In order to acknowledge DLR receipt, the receiving end point must reply back with exactly the following html body content:

ACK/Jasmin
https://docs.jasminsms.com/en/latest/apis/ja-http/index.html

```
<?php

$love=$_POST["id"];
$l=$_POST["level"];
//echo "welcome".$love."<br>";
//echo "welcome".$l."<br>";
header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK','Content-Type: text/plain');
echo '<body>ACK/jasmin</body>';


//use Swoole\Http\Server as HttpServer;

//$server = new HttpServer('127.0.0.1', 9000);
//$server->on('start', function ($server) {
//    echo "Server started at http://127.0.0.1:9000\n";
//});
//$server->on('request', function ($request, $response) {
//    $response->header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');
//    $response->end("ACK/jasmin");
//});
//$server->start();
?>
```

this is the log file for different types of tries i did

2021-05-10 15:54:10 ERROR    6342 Throwing HTTP/DLR [msgid:0e5e0cdc-e5f8-4122-ab4a-497d02930ca6] to (https://localhost/php): RequestTransmiss>
2021-05-10 15:54:10 WARNING  6342 Message try-count is 4 [msgid:0e5e0cdc-e5f8-4122-ab4a-497d02930ca6]: purged from queue
2021-05-10 15:57:17 ERROR    6342 Throwing HTTP/DLR [msgid:253e4cd1-d2d9-4298-b611-f2f9066d379d] to (http://localhost/php): ResponseFailed([<>
2021-05-10 15:57:17 ERROR    6342 Throwing HTTP/DLR [msgid:88e09ccd-6e9b-4360-9de2-4cea8d2c240e] to (http://localhost/php): ResponseFailed([<>
2021-05-10 15:57:47 ERROR    6342 Throwing HTTP/DLR [msgid:253e4cd1-d2d9-4298-b611-f2f9066d379d] to (http://localhost/php): ResponseFailed([<>
2021-05-10 15:57:47 ERROR    6342 Throwing HTTP/DLR [msgid:88e09ccd-6e9b-4360-9de2-4cea8d2c240e] to (http://localhost/php): ResponseFailed([<>
2021-05-10 15:58:17 ERROR    6342 Throwing HTTP/DLR [msgid:253e4cd1-d2d9-4298-b611-f2f9066d379d] to (http://localhost/php): ResponseFailed([<>
2021-05-10 15:58:17 ERROR    6342 Throwing HTTP/DLR [msgid:88e09ccd-6e9b-4360-9de2-4cea8d2c240e] to (http://localhost/php): ResponseFailed([<>
2021-05-10 15:58:47 ERROR    6342 Throwing HTTP/DLR [msgid:253e4cd1-d2d9-4298-b611-f2f9066d379d] to (http://localhost/php): ResponseFailed([<>
2021-05-10 15:58:47 WARNING  6342 Message try-count is 4 [msgid:253e4cd1-d2d9-4298-b611-f2f9066d379d]: purged from queue
2021-05-10 15:58:47 ERROR    6342 Throwing HTTP/DLR [msgid:88e09ccd-6e9b-4360-9de2-4cea8d2c240e] to (http://localhost/php): ResponseFailed([<>
2021-05-10 15:58:47 WARNING  6342 Message try-count is 4 [msgid:88e09ccd-6e9b-4360-9de2-4cea8d2c240e]: purged from queue
2021-05-10 16:05:33 ERROR    6342 Throwing HTTP/DLR [msgid:24e38152-79f8-45d2-8f3f-90e639e26d61] to (http://localhost/php): ResponseFailed([<>
2021-05-10 16:05:33 ERROR    6342 Throwing HTTP/DLR [msgid:ab4cb922-4a36-4f12-b4f0-0e1cfb0b1fb3] to (http://localhost/php): ResponseFailed([<>
2021-05-10 16:06:03 ERROR    6342 Throwing HTTP/DLR [msgid:24e38152-79f8-45d2-8f3f-90e639e26d61] to (http://localhost/php): ResponseFailed([<>
2021-05-10 16:06:03 ERROR    6342 Throwing HTTP/DLR [msgid:ab4cb922-4a36-4f12-b4f0-0e1cfb0b1fb3] to (http://localhost/php): ResponseFailed([<>
2021-05-10 16:06:33 ERROR    6342 Throwing HTTP/DLR [msgid:24e38152-79f8-45d2-8f3f-90e639e26d61] to (http://localhost/php): ResponseFailed([<>
2021-05-10 16:06:33 ERROR    6342 Throwing HTTP/DLR [msgid:ab4cb922-4a36-4f12-b4f0-0e1cfb0b1fb3] to (http://localhost/php): ResponseFailed([<>
2021-05-10 16:07:03 ERROR    6342 Throwing HTTP/DLR [msgid:24e38152-79f8-45d2-8f3f-90e639e26d61] to (http://localhost/php): ResponseFailed([<>
2021-05-10 16:07:03 WARNING  6342 Message try-count is 4 [msgid:24e38152-79f8-45d2-8f3f-90e639e26d61]: purged from queue
2021-05-10 16:07:03 ERROR    6342 Throwing HTTP/DLR [msgid:ab4cb922-4a36-4f12-b4f0-0e1cfb0b1fb3] to (http://localhost/php): ResponseFailed([<>
2021-05-10 16:07:03 WARNING  6342 Message try-count is 4 [msgid:ab4cb922-4a36-4f12-b4f0-0e1cfb0b1fb3]: purged from queue
2021-05-10 16:07:16 INFO     6342 Throwed DLR [msgid:02f28f1c-1e89-4cc3-b128-b86deeecf81b] to http://localhost/php/ack.php.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use HTML tags. The response text should only be "ACK/Jasmin".

```
<?php

$love=$_POST["id"];
$l=$_POST["level"];
//echo "welcome".$love."<br>";
//echo "welcome".$l."<br>";
header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK','Content-Type: text/plain');
echo 'ACK/Jasmin';
```